# unify neon assembly on both iOS and android

Tags: ios, xcode, assembly, android-ndk, arm

I want to use unified NEON assembly code on both IOS(Xcode4.2) and Android(ndk r7). But their macro definition are so different:

IOS:

.macro TestMacro  3

vext.8      $2, $0, $1, #1

.endm

ndk r7:

.macro TestMacro  ref,src,dst

vext.8      \dst,\ref,\src, #1

.endm

Any idea to unify them?Thanks.

Comment: For situations like this, I would write a script which converts one form to the other.

Comment: I am with @BitBank on this one. Write a script which converts one to the other. Or write the actual assembly in your own macro-language that  is easily translated by script to whichever you need right now. The first is probably faster to do, but if you need to do this for lots of files and want to translate this for some third compiler (RVCT for instance) it might be easier to create your own language.

Answer (score 1):

I use separate macro definitions for ios and android

```
example.S

#ifdef __MACH__

; iOS
.macro TestMacro
    vext.8 $2, $0, $1, #1
.endm

#else//__MACH__

; Android NDK
.macro TestMacro ref,src,dst
    vext.8 \dst,\ref,\src, #1
.endm

#endif//__MACH__
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C preprocessor to enable a "new" macro syntax as follows:

```
#include "macros.h"

.macro M_DEMO M3ARGS
   #define ref MARG0
   #define src MARG1
   #define dst MARG2

   vext.8 dst, ref, src, #1

   #undef ref
   #undef src
   #undef dst
.endm
```

where the `macros.h` header file contains:

```
#ifndef __MACROS_H__
#define __MACROS_H__

#ifdef __MACH__

    /*
     * iOS macro support
     */

    // Number of arguments in macro definition
    #define M0ARGS
    #define M1ARGS
    #define M2ARGS
    #define M3ARGS
    #define M4ARGS
    #define M5ARGS
    #define M6ARGS
    #define M7ARGS
    #define M8ARGS
    #define M9ARGS
    #define M10ARGS

    // Macro arguments
    #define MARG0 $0
    #define MARG1 $1
    #define MARG2 $2
    #define MARG3 $3
    #define MARG4 $4
    #define MARG5 $5
    #define MARG6 $6
    #define MARG7 $7
    #define MARG8 $8
    #define MARG9 $9

#else

    /* 
     * Android macro support
     */

    // Number of arguments in macro definition
    #define M0ARGS
    #define M1ARGS  $0
    #define M2ARGS  $0, $1
    #define M3ARGS  $0, $1, $2
    #define M4ARGS  $0, $1, $2, $3
    #define M5ARGS  $0, $1, $2, $3, $4
    #define M6ARGS  $0, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
    #define M7ARGS  $0, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6
    #define M8ARGS  $0, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7
    #define M9ARGS  $0, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8
    #define M10ARGS $0, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9

    // Macro arguments
    #define MARG0 \$0
    #define MARG1 \$1
    #define MARG2 \$2
    #define MARG3 \$3
    #define MARG4 \$4
    #define MARG5 \$5
    #define MARG6 \$6
    #define MARG7 \$7
    #define MARG8 \$8
    #define MARG9 \$9

#endif

#endif // __MACROS_H__
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing assembler file, try using GCC intrinsics from C/C++ source. Or GCC inline asm.

Comment: Instead of using GCC intrinsics just don't use macro should be a better choice ;) But this is not the response to the question !